# python int to bytearray does not convert properly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, type-conversion

I am trying to convert int to bytearray as follows:

```
test = bytearray(struct.pack(">I", 60000)[2:])
print(test)
```

The output is:

```
bytearray(b'\xea`')
```

Instead of:

```
bytearray(b'\xea\x60')
```

What seems to be the problem? and what could I do to have the "correct" output?

Comment: There is no difference between b'\xea`' and b'\xea\x60' - try printing b'\xea\x60' and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings and bytes, Python shows the ASCII representation of a codepoint if it falls within the *print-able* ASCII range, otherwise, it shows that as Hex.

As `\x60` is the codepoint for ` in ASCII, you're getting that. This is only for the representation purposes, all operations on them uses the codepoint underneath.

You can check this from your REPL:

```
In [1]: '\x60'
Out[1]: '`'

In [2]: b'\x60'
Out[2]: b'`'
```